# removing a row and column at the same time python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I know how to remove a row & column of an array

```
np.delete(l_mat, (0), axis=0)
np.delete(l_mat, (0), axis=1)
```

but how do i remove it the 1st row & column at the same time?

any help would be grateful,

Comment: For a single row or column, `np.delete` concatenates the two ranges on either side of the deleted one.  To do both, you would have to concatenate 4 blocks (`np.block` might work).  Alternatively create a target array, and copy the 4 keeper to it.

Comment: `np.ascontiguousarray(l_mat[1:, 1:])`?